# ASP.NET Core on Azure throw "The client certificate credentials were not recognized"

Tags: c#, azure, ssl, asp.net-core, client-certificates

My setup is similar to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550870/azure-asp-net-core-2-0-invoking-post-with-httpclient-using-a-client-certificat)

My ASP.NET Web App connects to a third party service which requires client certificates. Begin a multitenant application, I've a client certificate for each customer, stored inside a database. Skipping the code to retrieve the certificate from database, I do something like this:

```
  HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
  X509Certificate2 customerCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFromDatabase, "", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
  httpClientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(customerCertificate);
  httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
  httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
```

This code works flawlessly on my Windows 10 development PC.
When published to an Azure Web App it fails 20% of time with the following error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.  System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The client certificate credentials were not recognized.

I've written a test method which calls the third party service as fast as it can, switching certificate every time. This one works on my PC, and fails 80% of times on Azure (same error as above).

The solution proposed on the SO post above does not apply to me: I should have to load hundreads of certificates.

To troubleshoot the issue it could be usefull to execute a packet capture.
But, AFAIK, this is not possibile with Azure Web Apps (can be done with Virtual Machines and Network  Watcher).

Comment: Are you also disposing the `HttpClient` objects? MS recommends reusing a single `HttpClient` when possible, I'm wondering if instantiating "hundreds" of them are causing app pool recycles or something similar.

Comment: i hve the same issue did you figure out how to fix this? i have it all the time

Comment: No solution yet, but I've found I can packet capture an Azure Web App. There is a "Diagnostics" "Collect Network Trace" button, which does not work.But I can start the capture from command line with ArmClient. Something like this 
ArmClient.exe POST “/subscriptions/<your_subscription>/resourceGroups/<your_resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<your_site>/networkTrace/start?durationInSeconds=60&api-version=2016-08-01”